# UrlGenerationError within Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, haml, nested-routes

I have a nested route but I am getting the error of missing required keys: [:product_id]. I am passing this via the link_to method though it doesn't appear to be working

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/merchandise/variants", :locale=>#<Product id: 7, name: "Latte", description: nil, product_keywords: [], product_type_id: 1, prototype_id: nil, permalink: "latte", available_at: nil, deleted_at: "2016-06-13 13:41:47", meta_keywords: "", meta_description: "", featured: false, description_markup: nil, brand_id: nil, created_at: "2016-06-13 13:41:47", updated_at: "2016-06-13 13:41:47">, :product_id=>#<Variant id: nil, product_id: 7, sku: nil, price: #<BigDecimal:7fb49c1cf540,'0.0',9(18)>, cost: #<BigDecimal:7fb49c1cf0b8,'0.0',9(18)>, master: false, deleted_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>} missing required keys: [:product_id]
```

HAML Template

```
- title "New Variant (#{@product.name})"
= link_to "Back to Product", admin_merchandise_product_path(@product), class: 'button small'
= form_for @variant, :url  => admin_merchandise_product_variants_path(@product,@variant), :html => {:class => ''}  do |form|
  = render :partial => '/admin/merchandise/variants/form', :locals => {:form => form}
  .generic_submit_button
    = submit_tag "Create",
```

ROUTES

```
namespace :admin do
namespace :merchandise do
resources :products do
          member do
            get :add_properties
            put :activate
          end
          resources :variants
        end
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: @oreoluwa added the routes hopefully this will help

Comment: What happens when you remove the `@variant` from the `form_for`?

Comment: that resolves the issue, why didn't i see that earlier

Comment: Ok, let me add that as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the `@variant` from the `form_for`.